# if statment within an echo using ternary operators

Tags: php, if-statement, echo, ternary-operator

I have the following echo statement:

```
echo '<li><a href="'. esc_url(add_query_arg( 'booking-id', $the_query->post->ID, site_url( '/pay-deposit/' ) )) .'">Pay deposit</a></li>';
```

I want to add the class "disabled" to the link when a parameter = 1

Here is what I am trying using ternary operators

```
    $is_deposit_paid = get_post_meta( $the_query->post->ID, 'deposit_paid', true );
    echo '<li><a '.( $is_deposit_paid = 1) ? "disabled" .' href="'. esc_url(add_query_arg( 'booking-id', $the_query->post->ID, site_url( '/pay-deposit/' ) )) .'">Pay deposit</a></li>';
```

however this produces a syntax error. How do I write this out correctly?

Comment: `$is_deposit_paid = 1` will always be true, this is not a comparison.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are three issues to solve:

- ternary operator requires ... 3 arguments (surprise!), so after the second, you need to add the `:` and the string you want in the `else` case.
- the whole ternary expression should be put in brackets (not the condition) before you apply the dot operator to it in building your string.
- You need to compare, not assign (`==` instead of `=`)

So this would do it:

```
$is_deposit_paid = get_post_meta( $the_query->post->ID, 'deposit_paid', true );
echo '<li><a '.( $is_deposit_paid == 1  ? "disabled" : "") . 
    ' href="'. esc_url(add_query_arg( 'booking-id', $the_query->post->ID, 
        site_url( '/pay-deposit/' ) )) . 
    '">Pay deposit</a></li>';
```

Comment: Nope. This is not a comparison but an assignment (= instead of ==). Thus, it will always be true.

Answer (score 1):

Just use a variable right after your function call with the class being "disabled" or nothing (""):

```
$is_deposit_paid = get_post_meta( $the_query->post->ID, 'deposit_paid', true );
$class = ($is_deposit_paid)?"disabled":"";
echo "<li><a $class href='". esc_url(add_query_arg( 'booking-id', $the_query->post->ID, site_url( '/pay-deposit/' ) )) ."'>Pay deposit</a></li>";
```

If you only need the class, you could even check the function call immediately:

```
$class = (get_post_meta( $the_query->post->ID, 'deposit_paid', true ))?"disabled":"";
```